# Sobre pacotes via Reflection x Manualmente

Tags: c#, socket, reflexão

Bom, pode ser que o título não tenha ficado muito explicativo, mas espero melhorar isso no conteúdo do tópico.

Fiz uma biblioteca em **C#** no qual até o momento, escreve pacotes manualmente, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
//Escrevendo o pacote
SocketPacket Packet = new SocketPacket(PacketID.AccountID);
Packet.WriteString(Username);
Packet.WriteString(Password);

Client.Socket.Send(Packet);

//Lendo o pacote
switch(Packet.ID)
{
 .....
    case PacketID.AccountID:
         string Username = Packet.ReadString();
         string Password = Packet.ReadString();
 .....
}
```

Está funcionando bem, mas como podem ver, sempre preciso ler e escrever os pacotes manualmente. Porém, tive uma ideia, na qual os dados do pacote ficariam armazenados numa classe, a qual implementaria uma interface, a obrigando a ter um método de execução, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class AccountPacket : IPacket
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }

   public void Execute()
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

Testando no servidor local, não há alteração drástica de velocidade, mas não tenho como testar em algum servidor remoto, no objetivo de verificar a velocidade de ambos os métodos.

Para quem já suportou minha mania por explicações extensas, a pergunta seria qual dos métodos seriam recomendados para um servidor, no caso exclusivo para jogos em tempo real (no qual pacotes são enviados sempre sem parar para vários clientes). No primeiro caso, seria algo feito manualmente, já no segundo, como disse, estou utilizando **Reflection**, junto do método **GetProperty**.

Agradeço a quem puder responder.

Comment: Apesar da longa explicação acho que falta algumas coisas fundamentais para entender o que está fazendo, o que deseja e se está tendo algum problema. O que já posso adiantar é que se precisa de performance não use *reflection*. Este é um recurso bem lento útil em casos onde se precisa um integração onde não tem outra forma ou precisa criar uma abstração para ganhar produtividade de programação. Performance se obtém abrindo mão da comodidade. Certamente tem alguma forma razoavelmente cômoda de fazer o mesmo sem reflexão. Provavelmente não no mesmo nível.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. Não tive problemas criando o método qual serializa os dados de certa classe e envia via socket, mas até o momento só pude testar por meios locais. Já utilizo esse método para serializar e deserialziar dados de certa tabela e salvar em um modelo, o qual funciona muito bem, mas como estaria falando de um socket utilizado para jogos (no caso em tempo real, com certa quantidade de pacotes enfileirados).

Comment: Testar por meios locais é o ideal, porque depois a infra vai degradar mais. Seria interessante fazer um*profiling* da aplicação pra descobrir os pontos exatos onde está tendo custo mais alto.